# How to enable linux support double backslashes "\\" as the path delimiter

Tags: linux, path, backslash

Assume we have a file /root/file.ini.

In Ubuntu's shell, we can show the content with this command,
less /root\\file.ini

However, in debian's shell, the command below will report that the file does not exist.

Does anybody happen to know how to make linux support "\\" as a path delimiter? I need to solve it because we have a software, which tries to access a file using "\\". It works fine in ubuntu, but not in debian.

Thanks

Comment: huh that sounds weird.. will try it on ubuntu. have you checked the shell global and user settings on ubuntu?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: A software uses backslash to concat a path string and filename string (got that from the log). It's not appropriate to update it now, so I'm trying to workaround it.

Comment: Do you have a file "root\file.ini" under ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

Linux cannot support `\` as a path delimiter (though perhaps it might be able to with substantial changes to the kernel). This is because `\` is a valid file name character. In fact the only characters not allowed as part of a file name are `/` and `\0` (the null character).

If this seems to be working under ubuntu, then I would check for the existence of a file called `root\file.ini` in `/`

I believe you will probably find it easier to make your program platform independent.

I found this [forum post](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-179376.html) which states `/` is a platform independent path delimiter in ANSI C any that file operations will automatically convert `/` to actual path delimiter used on the host OS.

Comment: It should be double backslash, not single back slash. "\\" (Sometimes I have to type 4 backslashes in stack overflow:(

Answer (score 1):

have you tried "\\\\" (4 backslashes) first and third one for escaping and second and the last one to rule them all?